# jquery assign variable to input value max

Tags: jquery, variables, input

I have an input form and I want to assign to the max field value a variable.

This variable is the width of a container.

Here my unput html code :

```
<input type="range" max="variable" step="1%" value="0"/>
```

How can I do it with jquery. Get the width of a container then assign it in the max of the input form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's one way to do it (have an additional input textbox to display the range's value).

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sQk8a/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="range" max="variable" step="1%" value="0"/>
    <input type="text" />
    <span></span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
// cache re-usable jQuery elements
var $container = $('#container'),
    $range = $('[type="range"]'),
    $rangeValue = $('[type="text"]');

// initialize values:

// set range max to container width
$range.attr('max', $container.width());
// set rangeValue to range's value
$rangeValue.val($range.val());
// display container's width
$container.find('span').text('container width: ' + $container.width());

// events:

// set the rangeValue on range change
$range.change(function() {
    $rangeValue.val($range.val());
});

// set the range on rangeValue change
$rangeValue.change(function() {
    $range.val($rangeValue.val());
});
```

Comment: Thank you I will try it. My input is for a scroll bar using jquery tools. I need to set dynamically the width of the scrollable container.

Comment: I made an example of what I want. I have a touch scroll bar to scroll content inside the #container. I want to set the width of the container inside the max value of the input scroll bar. http://jsfiddle.net/lolo34140/sQk8a/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the max attr
var arr = $("input").attr('max');
console.log(arr);  // variable 

// Set the max attr
$("input").attr('max', 100);

arr = $("input").attr('max');
console.log(arr);  // 100 

// Get the width of container and set the max attr
var width = $("#containerID").width()
$("input").attr('max', width);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it seems to not working... Does I need to do something in the html input code?

Comment: Set the `containerID` with the id of the container you are using!

Comment: I Already do it. It correctly assign the number but doesn't take it into consideration... If I set manually in the input form the value it works. If it's assign thank to jquery it doesn't have the same behaviour